# lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading '%20Web': The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my flutter run --varbose results

```
C:\Users\LENOVOORBIT>flutter run --verbose
[  +94 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +136 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +5 ms] 18a827f3933c19f51862dde3fa472197683249d6
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git tag --points-at 18a827f3933c19f51862dde3fa472197683249d6
[ +421 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 18a827f3933c19f51862dde3fa472197683249d6
[   +2 ms] 3.3.3
[  +71 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{upstream}
[  +94 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{upstream}
[   +2 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +82 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +143 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +96 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +2 ms] stable
[ +162 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +9 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +166 ms] executing: C:\Users\LENOVOORBIT\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[ +115 ms] List of devices attached
[  +10 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +17 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +51 ms] "flutter run" took 425ms.
[  +44 ms] Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
           This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
[   +9 ms]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      FlutterCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1495:9)
           #2      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:486:19)
           #3      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1330:11)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +264 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 256ms
[   +9 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +3 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +4 ms] exiting with code 1
```

i've been trying to build the apk but evertime i do that it throws these errors.

lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading '../../6valley%20Multi-Vendor%20E-commerce%20-%20Mobile%20App': The system cannot find the file specified.

lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading '%20Web': The system cannot find the file specified.

lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading '%20Seller%20and%20Admin%20Panel/User%20App/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

i'm new to app development ,so i don't know much about it

Comment: this problem occurred  from your local git . kindly fix your local git

Comment: I'm really sorry, but i don't know how

Comment: Please guide me and help me